# Plotting map points in different colours in R

Tags: coordinate-system, r, mapping, mapview, plotting

I am trying to use mapview() to plot some geographical data, but somehow I can't find a way to plot two different data sets in different colours.

In my case, I want to plot occurrences in summer and winter as two different colours, but it doesn't seem to apply.

But in the sample plot generated by the code appended, the data points in the 'sum' dataset haven't showed up.

```
 mapview(win, xcol = "Longitude", ycol = "Latitude", crs = 4269, grid = FALSE, col.regions="blue") + mapview(sum, xcol = "Longitude", ycol = "Latitude", crs = 4269, grid = FALSE, col.regions="red")
```

[image: Infact, all the plots across the data frames 'sum' and 'win' are not beng shown in this plot, I am not sure what I am doing wrong]

Comment: Have you tried zooming in? May be the blue points are there.

Comment: @Padmanabha No, the blue points should show up around Mongolia

Answer (score 1):

Either there are no points in the blue data or the red points are obscuring the blue points. Test:

```
win = data.frame(Longitude=1:5, Latitude=1:5)
sum = data.frame(Longitude=5:1, Latitude=1:5)
mapview(win, xcol = "Longitude", ycol = "Latitude", crs = 4269, grid = FALSE, col.regions="blue") + mapview(sum, xcol = "Longitude", ycol = "Latitude", crs = 4269, grid = FALSE, col.regions="red")
```

Impossible to tell if this is the case for your data without your data or if for some reason its not plotting the blue data because your version of the `turboEncabulator` package is version 420.69 or some other random reason I've just made up!

Try plotting in the other order. Try different symbols or opacity.

[image]